# C# / Azure AD / Graph API - set additional user attributes with Open Extensions

Tags: c#, graph, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to add some custom attributes to my newly created user objects in my Azure Active Directory with Microsoft Graph.

My code looks like this:

```
public async Task addUser(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            var mail = firstName.ToLower() + "." + lastName.ToLower() + "@mail.com";
            var user = new User
            {
                AccountEnabled = true,
                UserPrincipalName = mail,
                PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                {
                    ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
                    Password = randomString(10) // I wrote a dedicated function here
                },
            };


            var res = await graphServiceClient
                .Users
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(user);

            await addExtension(res.Id);
        }
```

```
public async Task addExtension(string id)
        {
            var extension = new OpenTypeExtension
            {
                ExtensionName = "com.test.test", // necessary I guess
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        {"NewAttribute1", "Batman"},
                        {"NewAttribute2" , "Spiderman"}
                    }
            };


            await graphServiceClient
               .Users[id]
               .Extensions
               .Request()
               .AddAsync(extension);
        }
```

The error message, that I'm currently receiving is:

```
Message: One or more properties contains invalid values.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:

...
```

I've orientated myself here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/opentypeextension-post-opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I hope someone can help,
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make my program work. The code above is actually correct and is now doing fine for me, after some adjustments.

I had to read the extension seperately, as seen below. Accessing the `user.Extensions` property didn't work for me. Hope this helps someone in the future :)

```
public async Task getUserExtensions(string userID, string extensionID)
        {
            var extension = await configuration
                .configure()
                .Users[userID]
                .Extensions[extensionID]
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();

            foreach (var item in extension.AdditionalData)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} | {item.Value}");
            }
        }
```